# Rebinding in a custom STL allocator with pre-allocated block

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, c++11, allocator

I'm going to build a *custom allocator*, preallocating a big block (array) for storing `N` elements of some class `T`, and then just increase an index inside the array to service allocation requests.

Since I *don't* want any initialization for the elements in the pre-allocated block, something like this won't work:

```
T buffer[N];
```

because in this case `T`'s constructor will be called for the `N` elements of the block.

Since my understanding is that `std::aligned_storage` doesn't call `T`'s constructor, I thought of using `std::aligned_storage`, something like this:

```
std::aligned_storage<
    N * sizeof(T),
    std::alignment_of<T>::value 
>::type buffer;

T* base = static_cast<T*>( static_cast<void*>(&buffer) );
```

And then the allocator can just increment the base pointer when an allocation for a T is requested (until `(base+N)`), and T can be constructed *in place* (with placement `new`) when needed.

I'd like to use this scheme to define a *custom allocator for STL containers*. However, it seems to me that there could be a problem here for **rebinding**. In fact, if my understanding is correct, an STL allocator should support rebinding from a type `T` to a type `U`, e.g. because containers like `std::list<T>` (or other node-based containers like `std::map`) use allocators to allocate *nodes* that are not actually of type `T`, but of different type `U` (containing `T` and other "header" overhead information for the node).
So, would the aforementioned `std::aligned_storage` approach work well for rebinding? Or (as I think) a correct alignment for `T`s does *not* imply a correct alignment for another different type `U`?

How could this problem be solved?

How could I define the aforementioned `buffer` to make it work also for rebinding to some different type `U`?

Should this problem be attacked from a different perspective? If so, what?

Comment: Can't you just use `std::alignment_of<std::max_align_t>::value` instead, to make it properly aligned for any type supported by the C++ standard allocators? Of course this won't work for types with special (more strict) alignment requirements (best example SSE), but those are in the end always a problem, even for the standard allocators.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are on the right track.

One irritating details is that copies of allocators must compare equal, even converting (rebound) copies.  Comparing equal means they can deallocate each other's pointers.  So a container such as `std::list<int>` will rebind `your_alloc<int>` to `your_alloc<node<int>>` and then construct a `your_alloc<node<int>>` using a `your_alloc<int>`.  And technically your `your_alloc<node<int>>` has to deallocate a pointer allocated by `your_alloc<int>`.

[Here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html) is my attempt to meet this requirement.  Feel free to copy/modify/abuse this code.  My intent is to educate, not become the world's allocator supplier (which wouldn't exactly be lucrative anyway :-)).

This example takes a slightly different approach to alignment:  I happen to know that on my platform of interest (OS X, iOS) that `malloc` returns 16 byte aligned memory, and so that's all my custom allocator needs to return.  You could change that number to whatever is appropriate for your system.

This hardwiring of alignment means that a single pool can safely supply several `allocator<int>` and `allocator<node<int>>`, as they are all 16-byte aligned (and that's enough).  And it also means that copies, even converted copies, can detect when the pointer is pointing into the buffer, since copies all share the same buffer.

Said slightly differently, the C++ committee has effectively specified that allocators are reference types:  copies are equivalent and point to the same memory pool.

You can get away with cheating, using memory pools actually embedded into the allocator, but only with some containers on some implementations, and you can't back that up with a quote from the standard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions and for sharing your sample allocator code.

Comment: So if you want, say, 64-byte alignment (for cache-alignment purposes e.g.) from the `stack_allocator`, do you also need to redefine the global `::operator new` to provide the same 64-byte alignment?

Comment: @rhalbersma, you could do, or you could always request an additional `64 - alignof(std::max_align_t)` from `::operator new` and then only start using it on the 64-byte boundary (but you'd need to somehow pass the original unaligned pointer back to `::operator delete`)

Comment: *"I happen to know that on my platform of interest (OS X, iOS) that malloc returns 16 byte aligned memory, and so that's all my custom allocator needs to return"* - In fact this should be easy to make platform-independent by using `alingof(std::max_align_t)`, shouldn't it (even if this is of rather theoretical nature and 16 is probably always a fine value, anyway)?

Comment: @JonathanWakely So the only option is to do bookkeeping and store the pointers (i.e., aligned pointer a is in fact `::new` pointer b, which can be `::delete`d)? Obviously this wouldn't be a problem if we didn't have to rebind the allocator to support storage for different objects of various sizes.

Comment: That's not the only option, you can store a "cookie" pointing to the start of the block within the block itself, just before the aligned pointer. (This starts to waste a lot of space for small allocations though)

Comment: The link is dead. Could you fix it? I'm very much interested in a solution to this problem.

Comment: @dshin:  Thanks for the ping.  Fixed.